# How to access a script variable outside the script tag in a JSP page?

Tags: javascript, jsp, variables

The sample code is given below,,

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var i=123;
alert("Value of i= "+i);
</script>

<!-- I need to access the variable "i" here.
     And store it in an integer variable.
 -->

</body>
```

Comment: So you need to access javascript outside script tags ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Comment: JSP or JavaScript? Seems you start to confuse things.

Comment: It is a JSP page. Ineed to access the variable "i" in the commented region.

Comment: Yes adeneo, I need to access the variable "i" outside the script tag.

Comment: Can I store the value of "i" in session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, or you can but with frameworks like [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) or [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/). Take a tour on these page.